# Two-dimensional apply in R?

Tags: r, multidimensional-array, apply, higher-order-functions

I have two arrays

```
chemArr = c("water","oil",...(lots of values omitted)...,"hydrogen")
timeArr = c("0", "8hr", "12hr", "24hr", "36hr", "48hr", "72hr")
```

and I would like to build a data frame

```
chem  0               8hr               ... 72hr
water f("water", "0") f("water", "8hr") ...
...
```

where `f` is a function I have written. Is there a good way to do this in R?

In my particular case it would be more efficient to make a function taking `chem` and returning a column for each time, since each of these share calculations. But since the total time required is small I could do it some other way if it's more convenient.

Comment: Try `mapply` , see `?mapply`

Comment: ahh, didn't see that the second one is `f("water", "8hr")` as opposed to `f("oil", "8hr")`. In that case akrun' s suggestion `outer` is probably better, or a construction using `rep("chemArr", length("timeArr"))` in `mapply`.

Comment: I removed my earlier comment thinking that I was wrong.  My original comment was to use `outer`. i.e. `outer(timeArr, chemArr, FUN = f)`

Comment: @coffeinjunky  No problem with that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest using `expand.grid`, which creates a "long form" of all 2-way combination, and then use mapply to create the values from the function:

```
chemArr = c("water","oil","hydrogen")
timeArr = c("0", "8hr", "12hr", "24hr", "36hr", "48hr", "72hr")
mygrid <- expand.grid(chemArr, timeArr)
mygrid <- expand.grid(chems = chemArr, times = timeArr)
str(mygrid)
#'data.frame':  21 obs. of  2 variables:
# $ chems: Factor w/ 3 levels "water","oil",..: 1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3 1 ...
# $ times: Factor w/ 7 levels "0","8hr","12hr",..: 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 4 ...
# - attr(*, "out.attrs")=List of 2
#  ..$ dim     : Named int  3 7
#  .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr  "chems" "times"
#  ..$ dimnames:List of 2
#  .. ..$ chems: chr  "chems=water" "chems=oil" "chems=hydrogen"
#  .. ..$ times: chr  "times=0" "times=8hr" "times=12hr" "times=24hr" ... 

mygrid$f_value <- mapply(f, mygrid$chems, mygrid$times)
```

Comment: Oh, perhaps. The first version delivered a result with column names Var1 and Var2 and I wanted more meaningful names.

Answer (score 3):

To illustrate the solutions discussed in the comments:

```
one <- letters[1:3]
two <- letters[4:6]

one
[1] "a" "b" "c"
two
[1] "d" "e" "f"

mapply(paste0, one, two)
   a    b    c 
"ad" "be" "cf" 

mapply(paste0, sort(rep(one, length(two))), two)
   a    a    a    b    b    b    c    c    c 
"ad" "ae" "af" "bd" "be" "bf" "cd" "ce" "cf" 

mapply(paste0, one, list(two)) # courtesy of @thelatemail
     a    b    c   
[1,] "ad" "bd" "cd"
[2,] "ae" "be" "ce"
[3,] "af" "bf" "cf"

outer(one, two, paste0) # courtesy of @akrun
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,] "ad" "ae" "af"
[2,] "bd" "be" "bf"
[3,] "cd" "ce" "cf"
```

Comment: The `rep` is unnecessary in `mapply` - `mapply(paste0, one, list(two) )` for instance.

Comment: Thanks again @thelatemail I have updated the solution.